# Change text in webbrowser from form using class

Tags: c#, html, winforms

This is the HTML code for the TextBox in the web browser:

```
<textarea class="oracle-input">Når går bussen </textarea>
```

I want to change the text to the text I write in the form's TextBox, and on a button click, but how?

Comment: With jQuery: $(".oracle-input").val($("your-textbox-selector").val())

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery.

Some thing like this

```
$("button").on("click", function () {

   $(".oracle-input").val("value changed");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this on the server, I recommend using a little different markup. Change

```
<textarea class="oracle-input">Når går bussen </textarea>
```

to

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="OracleInputTextBox" 
     CssClass="oracle-input" TextMode="Multiline" />
```

This will render the text area element as a sever-side control, and you can modify it with your server-side code - on the server-side you will now have a field `OracleInputTextBox` within your page/control and you can change its text by using the following code:

```
OracleInputTextBox.Text = "new text";
```

The other answers have already provided you with ways to do this on the client side. If that is sufficient enough for you, there is not need for the server-side changes I have described.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean at client browser then
With jQuery:

```
$(".oracle-input").val($("your-textbox-selector").val())
```

Without jquery, pure javascript: google "getElementById"

Answer (score 0):

page1.aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtInput" runat="server" />
<asp:Button id="Button1" Text="Click" OnClick="Btn_Click"  runat="server"/>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtOutput" CssClass="oracle-input" TextMode="Multiline" rows="3" runat="server" />
```

page1.aspx.cs

```
protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblOutput.Text = TxtInput.Text;//update label
    TxtOutput.Text = TxtInput.Text;//update text box
}
```

I have added both a label and text box, just to show an additional control.

Answer (score 0):

with javascript you can try jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XgsQV/

```
<textarea class="oracle-input">Når går bussen </textarea>
<input type="button" value="change" onclick="changeText('second text');">

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(str)
{
var txtarea = document.getElementsByClassName("oracle-input");
txtarea[0].value = str;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on server-side, use an asp control, like `asp:TextBox`. If you need to do this on client-side, then use Javascript's `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName`.